# Collect data entering from other viewcontrollers in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 7 ViewControllers, first one is navigate to the five view controllers and the last one is to collect the data entering by user using text fields and replace them with local html form. I could get only data from one VC. So my question is how to get all the data entering from all VCs. here is 2nd VC

```
- (IBAction)btnOpenHTML:(id)sender {
SecondVC *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setValue:self.txtSchool1Dgree.text forKey:@"degree1"];
[dict setValue:self.txtSchool2Dgree.text forKey:@"degree2"];

obj.dicData = dict;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:true];}
```

and here is 3ed VC:

```
- (IBAction)btnOpenHTML:(id)sender {

SecondVC *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dict setValue:self.txtComp1Name.text forKey:@"comp1name"];
[dict setValue:self.txtComp2Name.text forKey:@"comp2name"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:true];}
```

same the rest 3VCs.

For the receiver VC

```
-(NSString *)getHTMLStirng {
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"resumeT" ofType:@"html"];
NSMutableString *strHTML = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

if (self.dicData) {
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#DEGREE1" withString:[_dicData valueForKey:@"degree1"]];
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#DEGREE2" withString:[_dicData valueForKey:@"degree2"]];
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#COMPANY1" withString:[_dicData valueForKey:@"comp1name"]];
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#COMPANY" withString:[_dicData valueForKey:@"comp2name"]];
    }return strHTML;}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: First try to solve your issue with 2 vew controllers, then extend it to 3. For reduced problems it's most often easier to find the bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to do in 3rd VC next:

```
obj.dicData = [self.dicData dictionaryByAddEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
```

And you are not need NSMutableDictionary for dict:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"comp1name" : self.txtComp1Name.text,
    @"comp2name" : self.txtComp2Name.text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's better to make some common model for all of these controllers? so each of them could work with their specific part of this model. it might be a new class or just NSMutableDictionary object - it's up to you.

the controller could get access to the model via AppDelegate or special manager (singleton).